# ZTE F670 V1.1.10P3T21 encrypted config.bin

Tags: linux, firmware-analysis, router

I want to decrypt config.bin
For this I found in cspd
following code

```
   undefined4 CspDBInitPdtInterface(undefined4 *param_1)

{
  dbAddCfgItem(0xffff,0,"/userconfig/cfg/db_user_cfg.xml");
  dbAddCfgItem(0xffff,1,"/userconfig/cfg/db_default_cfg.xml");
  dbAddCfgItem(0xffff,2,"/userconfig/cfg/db_backup_cfg.xml");
  param_1[2] = 1;
  param_1[3] = CspDBSetBackupItem;
  param_1[7] = dbPdtTransferCfg;
  *param_1 = 0;
  strncpy((char *)((int)param_1 + 0x117),"L04&Product@5A238dc79b15726d5c05",0x20);
  strncpy((char *)(param_1 + 0x4e),"ZTE%FN$GponNJ025678b02a85c63c705",0x20);
  PdtDBSetUserCfgAESCBCEncryKey((int)param_1 + 0xd5,(int)param_1 + 0xf6,0x21,0x21);
  return 0;
}





 void PdtDBSetUserCfgAESCBCEncryKey(char *param_1,char *param_2,size_t param_3,size_t param_4)` 

{
  int iVar1;
  undefined auStack_74 [64];
  uint local_34; 
 
  local_34 = (uint)(param_2 == (char *)0x0 || param_1 == (char *)0x0);
  if (param_2 != (char *)0x0 && param_1 != (char *)0x0) {
    memset(auStack_74,local_34,0x40);
    iVar1 = GetTagParam(0x200,auStack_74,0x40);
    if (iVar1 == 0) {
      snprintf(param_1,param_3,"8dc79b15726d5c46%s",auStack_74);
      snprintf(param_2,param_4,"678b02a85c63c786%s",auStack_74);
    }
    else {
      strncpy(param_1,"8dc79b15726d5c46d412af8cbed65aad",param_3 - 1);
      strncpy(param_2,"678b02a85c63c786def4523b061265e8",param_4 - 1);
    }
  }
  return;
}
```

Did I understand correctly that there are two keys?